# remove value on field on submit if value is equal to default value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have a form that uses a servlet I don't have access to for validation. The powers that be want the field to be prefilled with a value "Enter promotion code" - unfortunately, since placeholder doesn't work with IE, the field is going through the validation process on submit for the default text.

Is there a way to clear the value on that field if the value equals the default text when the form is submitted? (jquery or javascript)

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should toss this somewhere on load. 
If you aren't using jQuery on the page yet, it'll look like this:

```
$(function() {
    // when the submit button is pressed
    $('#yourForm').submit(function() {
        if($('#yourInputBox').val() == YOUR_DEFAULT_STRING)
            $('#yourInputBox').val(''); // clear the value
        return true; // submit the form
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided any code to work with, but conceptually you can hook the submit function for your form with javascript, check to see if the prefilled value is still in the form and clear it if so and then allow the submit to proceed.